# Python: Уведомление в Центр Уведомлений Windows

Tags: python, windows

Как, используя Python, послать уведомление в Центр Уведомлений Windows 10?

Comment: Есть статья на [англоязычном Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А для десятой винды нужно использовать модуль Plyer, здесь всё ещё проще

```
import plyer
plyer.notification.notify
  ( message='Собственно сообщение',
    app_name='Название твоего приложения',
    app_icon='sample.jpg',
    title='Заголовок', )
```

Не забудь ещё установить его через pip

```
pip3 install Plyer
```

или официальный сайт https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 2):

[Вот один пример](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/notificationhubs-rest-python/NotificationHub.py)

Нашёл это [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-python-push-notification-tutorial)

Используйте как модуль:

```
from NotificationHub import NotificationHub
nh = NotificationHub('Endpoint...;SharedAccessKeyName...;SharedAccessKey...')
nh.send_notification('Твоё сообщение')
```