# Не могу сделать уведомление для центра уведомлений windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, уведомления

Нашел в интернете код приложения, в котором можно делать заметку на определенный день, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наступлении даты заметки в центр уведомлений windows приходило уведомление о заметке, хотел сделать функцию, которая бы сравнивала сегодняшнюю дату с датой заметки, и если дата такая же, то приходило уведомление, однако не вышло. Пытался найти информацию как сделать по другому, но тоже не получилось. Как сделать уведомления на windows  когда наступает день на котором есть заметка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - вот как должно примерно выглядеть уведомление

Вот часть кода, которая отвечает за дату заметки

```
import random
import logging
import requests
import json
import datetime

from app_modules.db_handler import DatabaseHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class TaskListModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task_list = None
        self.db = None

        self.task_addition_date = datetime.datetime.now()

        self.retrieve_tasks_from_db()

    def retrieve_tasks_from_db(self):
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.create_table('tasks')
            self.db.select('tasks')
            self.task_list = self.db.cur.fetchall()

    def add_task_to_db(self, task, details, deadline):
        logger.debug('Tryout of addition of a "%s" task to database', task)
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.insert('tasks', task, details, self.task_addition_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y.%H"), deadline)
            logger.info('Task "%s" successfully added to a database', task)

    def update_task_data(self, task_name, new_task_name, new_details, new_deadline):
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.update('tasks', task_name, new_task_name, new_details, new_deadline)
            logger.info('Task "%s" details changed', task_name)

    def delete_task_from_db(self, task):
        logger.debug('Tryout of deletion of a "%s" task from a database', task)
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.delete('tasks', task)
            logger.info('Task "%s" successfully deleted from a database', task)

    def archive_task(self, task):
        logger.debug('Tryout of archiving of a "%s" task', task)
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.create_table('archive')
            self.db.transfer_data_between_tables('tasks', 'archive', task)
            logger.info('Task "%s" successfully archived', task)


class MotivationalQuoteModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quote = None
        self.get_quote_from_api()

    def get_quote_from_api(self):
        """ Gets random motivational quote from api """
        url = "https://type.fit/api/quotes?fbclid=IwAR066CVqn2qdvUIEBui3J2r-xre3ZcaQrfKJkqJmf4Drj2FH-qgW1DgcD4c"
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                self.quote = random.choice(data)
                while not self.is_quote_valid():
                    self.quote = random.choice(data)
        except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
            logger.exception("Connection couldn't be established...", exc_info=True)
            self.get_quote_from_file()

    

    def is_quote_valid(self):
        """ Checks if quote's text length isn't bigger than 85 characters """
        if len(self.quote["text"]) > 85:
            logger.debug("Text too long to be displayed, trying again...")
            return False
        else:
            if self.quote["author"] is None or self.quote["author"] == "" or self.quote["author"] == "null":
                logger.debug("Author data doesn't exist, setting it to 'Unknown'... ")
                self.quote['author'] = 'Unknown'
            return True


class Archive:
    def __init__(self):
        self.archived_tasks = None
        self.db = None

    def retrieve_tasks_from_db(self):
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.create_table('archive')
            self.db.select('archive')
            self.archived_tasks = self.db.cur.fetchall()
            print(self.archived_tasks)

    def dump_archive(self):
        with DatabaseHandler() as self.db:
            self.db.drop_table('archive')
```

Вот ссылка на Яндекс Диск, на котором находится весь код: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/jO0Uc9D2eEWHYg

Comment: Как-то игрался с этими уведомлениями, попробуйте: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9f946c83dfbd66ed8507af2876cec9f35ada58cf/winapi__windows__ctypes/windows__toast_balloontip_notifications/run_notify.py#L20

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561068/python-%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-windows

Comment: @S.Nick сами уведомления есть, тут проблема как связать уведомления и заметки ( так чтобы приходило уведомления о заметке, когда наступало время которое ты поставил эту заметку )

Comment: @gil9red у меня проблема именно со связью уведомлений и заметок, я  не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы при наступлении определенной даты приходило уведомление

Comment: @ivapop, в отдельном скрипте или в отдельном потоке запрашивайте заметки с фильтром по времени (например, те, чья дата и время больше или равна текущей), те, что подходят условию отображайте в уведомлении и, например, помечаете в базе данных, что уведомление было показано. Делал пример бота телеграмма для уведомлений: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/291848808b88503e89e395a7549b45dd46acb50b/telegram_bot_examples/reminder/main.py#L31

Comment: @ivapop, опубликуйте ваш проект на github.com

Comment: @S.Nick вот ссылка на GitHub - https://github.com/ivapop1/PyQt5-Notes

Answer (score 0):

В class `DatabaseHandler` можно добавить метод выборки дедлайнов.

```
def select_by_deadline(self, table_name, task_deadline):
    self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE TaskDeadline='{task_deadline}';")
```

В class `TaskListModel` соответственно метод для выборки, далее уже запускать уведомления, ну и при смене суток соответсвенно повторять.

```
def retrieve_deadline_tasks_from_db(self):
    self.db.select_by_deadline('tasks', datetime.date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y") )
    self.deadlines = self.db.cur.fetchall()
    # вызывать уведомления
```

Для запуска можно использовать планировщик

`$ pip install` [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html)

добавление задачи, показать с интервалом 2 минуты

```
scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', minutes=2, id='my_job_id')
```

Функция `myfunc` соответсвенно должна извлекать из списка дедлайнов задачу и отображать ее

После чего можно остановить задачу отображения нотификаторов.
scheduler.remove_job('my_job_id')

Всего в модуле `apscheduler` есть три типа запуска задач:

1. `date`: используйте, если вы хотите запустить задание только один раз
   в определенный момент времени
2. `interval`: используйте, если вы хотите запускать задание через
   фиксированные промежутки времени
3. `cron`: используйте, если вы хотите периодически запускать задание в
   определенное время дня